# Filter Array of object by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with duplicates keys with javascript:

```
var transactions = [
          {
            id: 3,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'C',
            amount: 250,
            category: 'other',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'C',
            amount: 250,
            category: 'other',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
          }
        ];
```

and i need to filter o reduce the array based on "duplicate keys" lets says where
sourceAccount: 'A',targetAccount: 'C' and amount: 250 and i need to create a new array of objects with the duplicate ones. Hopefully with pure JS!

Edit

Expected value

```
var expected = [
          {
            id: 3,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            sourceAccount: 'A',
            targetAccount: 'B',
            amount: 100,
            category: 'eating_out',
            time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'
          }
        ];
```

As far all my intents y need to specified the value of the key, but it can be dynamically, so the idea is to map the array into a new array where sourceAccount, targetAccount, category and amount are the same value, without knowing the value before.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see any duplicate key here.

Comment: @KoshVery tried with reduce but i need a key as reference, so i have no clue where to start.

Comment: @OmarFaruque sourceAccount: 'A', is duplicate almost everywhere in the array.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to merge the data if `sourceAccount` and `targetAccount` are same. Please add the **expected output** for this input **in the question** itself. It's not clear at the moment.

Comment: @adiga var expected = [
    {
      id: 3,
      sourceAccount: 'A',
      targetAccount: 'B',
      amount: 100,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      sourceAccount: 'A',
      targetAccount: 'B',
      amount: 100,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
    }
  ];

the idea es to filter the array when the keys and the values are the same, but it can be dynamically, so i can't know the value

Comment: Is that the complete output you expect for this particular input? There are 4 instance of `A->B` and 2 instance of `A->C`. Why does your output have only 2 `A->B` items. Please **edit the question** and add the **complete** expected out.

Comment: Even the criteria for what items are considered *duplicate* is not clear. If there are 2 items with same `sourceAccount` and `targetAccount` they are considered duplicate? In winch case the output looks exactly like the input for your example? Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter method

```
var newArray = transactions.filter(f => f.sourceAccount =='A' && f.targetAccount == 'C' && f.amount == 250)
```

It will return array with all objects matching the criteria

Comment: It works if i provide the value for the keys, but i need to filter with out a reference, i meand the array should be filter without passing key=value, any idea?

Comment: But you can't do that - you specified the `key-value` pairs to us, so it won't happen automatically.

Comment: @JackBashford, i mean, the array can be made dinamically, so the values can change, i can't set in the filter functions the values because the array should be filtered by his own properties.

Comment: You will have to pass in something. Either values for known properties or property nanes you want to find duplicates for. You can't just look for duplicates on any combination of properties. Permutations to check could be massive.  Or I'm completely misunderstanding the question

Comment: i can pass the property key name, but not the value, in your example you are passing both f.sourceAccount =='A' , the idea is to get all object that match f.sourceAccount ==N where N can be any value

Answer (score 1):

Passing an anonymous method to javascript's filter that returns true or false method allows you to reduce the object in one shot:

```
var done = new Set()
transactions.filter(obj => {
  if (!done.has(obj.id)) {
    done.add(obj.id)
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
})
```